R lmer help understanding my mixed model output
Question: How does urbanization impact the body size of bee species that differ in their functional traits?
Something we may expect is that social bees are often larger and would be distributed differently across low, medium, and high urbanization levels. Perhaps the larger bodied individuals are found in high urban sites because they can travel further between fragmented areas.
Here are the functional traits I am looking at and to save space and time I just shrunk the table down and kept the genera name to just numbers for now:

So, I have a large dataframe that has bees sampled for each of my genera and I have these functional categories listed out for each one.
My model when running all functional traits as random effects:
mixed.lmer.all <- lmer(Head.Width ~ Urban.Intensity + (1|Diet) + 
                        (1|Sociality/Nesting), data=df)

The output is:
    Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
Formula: Head.Width ~ Urban.Intensity + (1 | Diet)
   Data: df

REML criterion at convergence: 12095.3

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-5.1916 -0.6149 -0.0474  0.8081  2.7484 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 Diet     (Intercept) 0.2591   0.5090  
 Residual             0.4091   0.6396  
Number of obs: 6209, groups:  Diet, 2

Fixed effects:
                      Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)            3.53413    0.36038   9.807
Urban.IntensityMEDIUM -0.07511    0.02141  -3.509
Urban.IntensityLOW    -0.02469    0.02215  -1.115

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) U.IMED
Urb.IMEDIUM -0.038       
Urbn.IntLOW -0.034  0.631
Analysis of Deviance Table (Type II Wald chisquare tests)

Response: Head.Width
                 Chisq Df Pr(>Chisq)    
Urban.Intensity 14.313  2  0.0007798 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

I have no idea if this is telling me that, when considering all three functional traits, there is a significant difference in bee body size with urbanization level, and it does not matter if the bees differ in functional traits? This is the part that is confusing me a lot.
I also ran these mixed models with each functional trait as a random effect individually, all showing me a significant result as well. But I am just so confused if it means that the functional trait does not matter.
EDIT: Sample of dataframe to test
> dput(df)
structure(list(Year = structure(c(2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 
3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 
3L), levels = c("2021", "2022", "2023"), class = "factor"),
SiteID = structure(c(19L, 
2L, 14L, 29L, 17L, 11L, 9L, 29L, 22L, 3L, 3L, 27L, 19L, 22L, 
11L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 27L, 14L, 4L, 21L, 3L, 9L, 9L, 13L, 1L, 15L, 
1L, 24L, 20L, 19L, 6L, 7L, 2L, 9L, 19L, 8L, 27L, 18L, 22L, 22L, 
13L, 3L, 13L, 21L, 3L, 3L, 8L, 19L, 11L, 12L, 9L, 17L, 25L, 25L, 
11L, 19L, 16L, 13L, 8L, 8L, 20L, 12L, 27L, 17L, 19L, 17L, 14L, 
22L, 27L, 20L, 16L, 9L, 19L, 9L, 3L, 9L, 27L, 22L, 17L, 28L, 
26L, 3L, 19L, 20L, 3L, 8L, 22L, 3L, 16L, 22L, 11L, 2L, 22L, 3L, 
19L, 27L, 15L, 22L, 1L, 19L, 22L, 29L, 27L, 8L, 26L, 5L, 9L, 
9L, 27L, 27L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 22L, 24L, 20L, 11L, 2L, 2L, 13L, 3L, 
19L, 23L, 18L, 18L, 20L, 3L, 1L, 6L, 13L, 21L, 19L, 18L, 19L, 
3L, 1L, 13L, 8L, 29L, 5L, 19L, 27L, 16L, 17L, 22L, 12L, 7L, 8L, 
20L, 17L, 13L, 9L, 9L, 3L, 11L, 17L, 9L, 27L, 22L, 29L, 16L, 
9L, 20L, 22L, 27L, 12L, 19L, 4L, 15L, 19L, 6L, 2L, 22L, 27L, 
27L, 9L, 22L, 16L, 22L, 12L, 19L, 22L, 19L, 14L, 27L, 16L, 19L, 
4L, 19L, 21L, 9L, 17L, 4L, 19L, 11L, 22L, 9L, 10L), levels = c("H02", 
"H03", "H04", "H05", "H06", "H07", "H08", "H09", "L01", "L02", 
"L04", "L05", "L06", "L07", "L08", "L09", "L10", "L12", "M01", 
"M02", "M03", "M04", "M05", "M06", "M08", "M09", "M10", "M11", 
"M12"), class = "factor"),
Genus = structure(c(4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
4L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 
1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 3L), levels = c("Agapostemon", "Bombus", "Ceratina", 
"Xenoglossa"), class = "factor"),
Sex = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L), levels = c("F", "M"), class = "factor"),
Urban.Intensity = structure(c(2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
    3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
    3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L), levels = c("HIGH", 
    "MEDIUM", "LOW"), class = "factor"),
Sociality = structure(c(2L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 3L), levels = c("Social", "Solitary", "Subsocial"
    ), class = "factor"),
Nesting = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L), levels = c("Cavity", "Ground"), class = "factor"),

Diet = structure(c(2L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), levels = c("Generalist", "Specialist"), class = "factor"),
Origin = c("Native", "Native", "Native", "Native", "Native", 
    "Native", "Native", "Native", "Native", "Native", "Native", 
    "Native", "Native", "Native", "Native", "Native", "Native", 
    "Native", "Native", "Native", "Native", "Native", "Native", 
    "Native", "Native", "Native", "Native", "Native", "Native", 
    "Native", "Native", "Native", "Native", "Native", "Native", 
    "Native", "Native", "Native", "Native", "Native", "Native", 
    "Native", "Native", "Native", "Native", "Native", "Native", 
    "Native", "Native", "Native", "Native", "Native", "Native", 
    "Native", "Native", "Native", "Native", "Native", "Native", 
    "Native", "Native", "Native", "Native", "Native", "Native", 
    "Native", "Native", "Native", "Native", "Native", "Native", 
    "Native", "Native", "Native", "Native", "Native", "Native", 
    "Native", "Native", "Native", "Native", "Native", "Native", 
    "Native", "Native", "Native", "Native", "Native", "Native", 
    "Native", "Native", "Native", "Native", "Native", "Native", 
    "Native", "Native", "Native", "Native", "Native", "Native", 
    "Native", "Native", "Native", "Native", "Native", "Native", 
    "Native", "Native", "Native", "Native", "Native", "Native", 
    "Native", "Native", "Native", "Native", "Native", "Native", 
    "Native", "Native", "Native", "Native", "Native", "Native", 
    "Native", "Native", "Native", "Native", "Native", "Native", 
    "Native", "Native", "Native", "Native", "Native", "Native", 
    "Native", "Native", "Native", "Native", "Native", "Native", 
    "Native", "Native", "Native", "Native", "Native", "Native", 
    "Native", "Native", "Native", "Native", "Native", "Native", 
    "Native", "Native", "Native", "Native", "Native", "Native", 
    "Native", "Native", "Native", "Native", "Native", "Native", 
    "Native", "Native", "Native", "Native", "Native", "Native", 
    "Native", "Native", "Native", "Native", "Native", "Native", 
    "Native", "Native", "Native", "Native", "Native", "Native", 
    "Native", "Native", "Native", "Native", "Native", "Native", 
    "Native", "Native", "Native", "Native", "Native", "Native", 
    "Native", "Native", "Native"),
Head.Width = c(3.92616, 2.541, 
    3.51288, 2.508, 1.9055, 3.66786, 3.97782, 2.574, 3.003, 3.036, 
    3.20292, 3.51288, 3.66786, 2.541, 3.8346, 3.5856, 3.40956, 
    3.8745, 3.82284, 2.904, 3.069, 4.18446, 3.77118, 2.805, 2.706, 
    3.46122, 4.1328, 4.23612, 2.706, 4.1328, 3.77118, 3.82284, 
    3.8745, 4.23612, 3.036, 2.937, 3.735, 4.08114, 3.82284, 2.937, 
    2.871, 2.97, 4.0836, 3.51288, 1.5936, 4.08114, 2.97, 3.71952, 
    3.71952, 2.739, 3.71952, 4.08114, 2.541, 1.419, 4.02948, 
    3.7848, 2.442, 3.3579, 3.8745, 2.541, 3.82284, 3.56454, 4.08114, 
    2.871, 1.452, 3.40956, 3.97782, 3.6354, 2.64, 2.97, 3.3579, 
    3.984, 3.25458, 2.442, 3.97782, 2.475, 3.82284, 2.805, 4.02948, 
    2.97, 3.25458, 4.1328, 4.02948, 1.7928, 3.56454, 3.92616, 
    3.5358, 4.1328, 2.871, 4.23612, 4.1328, 3.66786, 3.25458, 
    2.838, 3.82284, 3.003, 3.6852, 1.751, 3.71952, 3.6852, 3.92616, 
    3.77118, 2.871, 2.937, 2.541, 4.08114, 2.937, 2.475, 3.003, 
    3.036, 1.419, 3.25458, 4.02948, 2.838, 2.607, 2.475, 4.1328, 
    3.92616, 3.8745, 3.069, 2.904, 3.069, 3.15126, 3.71952, 2.871, 
    4.18446, 3.036, 3.20292, 3.25458, 2.607, 3.6162, 3.71952, 
    3.30624, 3.40956, 2.574, 2.508, 3.97782, 4.0338, 2.277, 3.97782, 
    2.64, 3.5856, 2.541, 3.66786, 4.0836, 3.6162, 3.77118, 3.0996, 
    2.541, 4.08114, 3.6162, 3.77118, 3.71952, 2.508, 2.64, 1.452, 
    2.805, 3.6162, 2.706, 2.442, 2.805, 3.71952, 3.56454, 2.541, 
    3.97782, 2.739, 3.6162, 3.71952, 2.871, 2.706, 3.6162, 3.003, 
    2.805, 3.46122, 2.706, 3.735, 3.0996, 3.82284, 2.541, 3.51288, 
    2.871, 3.66786, 3.486, 3.66786, 2.97, 2.376, 3.30624, 3.92616, 
    3.8745, 2.706, 2.871, 3.92616, 3.3864, 1.77675, 2.904, 3.3366, 
    3.6162, 2.574, 2.508, 1.743),
Wing.Wear = c(0, 3, 2, 3, 2, 
    1.5, 3, 0.5, 3.5, 1, 1, 2.5, 0, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 0.5, 2, 0, 0, 
    0.5, 3, 3, 0, 2.5, 5, 0.5, 0, 1.5, 0, 0.5, 2.5, 0, 2, 0, 
    0, 3, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 2.5, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 0, 
    1, 3, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0.5, 0, 4.5, 0, 0, 1.5, 
    0.5, 1, 3.5, 0, 3, 1, 0, 0.5, 0, 1.5, 0, 1.5, 5, 3, 1.5, 
    1, 0, 0, 4, 4, 4, 3, 2.5, 3.5, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 3.5, 3, 2.5, 
    0.5, 0.5, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 4.5, 4, 2.5, 2.5, 0.5, 
    4, 0.5, 3, 0.5, 0, 1, 4, 1, 0, 0, 0, 4, 2, 2.5, 1, 3.5, 3, 
    2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 0, 3, 2, 0, 0.5, 0, 4, 3, 0.5, 2, 0, 
    4, 2, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1.5, 3.5, 2.5, 0, 0.5, 3, 1, 0, 0, 2.5, 
    2.5, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3.5, 3.5, 0, 5, 1.5, 4.5, 0.5, 
    0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 5, 3.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3, 0.5, 0, 1, 1
    ),
Intertegular.Width = c(3.15126, 1.749, 3.46122, 1.749, 
    1.41625, 3.77118, 3.71952, 1.848, 2.244, 2.343, 3.0996, 3.0996, 
    2.89296, 1.683, 3.3366, 2.6394, 3.15126, 3.04794, 3.3579, 
    2.145, 2.343, 4.02948, 3.6162, 1.98, 1.947, 3.3579, 4.1328, 
    3.0996, 1.947, 3.20292, 3.6162, 2.8413, 3.8745, 4.1328, 2.112, 
    2.112, 2.8386, 3.20292, 3.6162, 2.145, 2.112, 2.046, 3.5856, 
    3.3579, 1.2948, 4.18446, 2.145, 3.71952, 3.15126, 1.881, 
    3.56454, 3.15126, 1.881, 1.188, 4.08114, 3.6852, 1.881, 3.25458, 
    3.56454, 1.782, 3.66786, 2.68632, 2.89296, 2.211, 1.32, 3.30624, 
    3.0996, 3.2868, 1.815, 2.211, 3.40956, 3.5358, 3.0996, 2.046, 
    3.04794, 1.683, 3.71952, 1.98, 4.02948, 2.376, 3.20292, 4.1328, 
    3.92616, 1.4442, 3.56454, 3.8745, 2.5896, 3.51288, 2.046, 
    4.54608, 4.1328, 3.66786, 3.0996, 2.046, 3.51288, 2.244, 
    2.8884, 1.3905, 3.71952, 3.5358, 3.8745, 4.08114, 2.112, 
    2.244, 1.881, 3.3579, 2.145, 1.749, 2.178, 2.211, 1.188, 
    3.25458, 3.3579, 2.013, 2.013, 1.782, 3.8745, 3.92616, 3.8745, 
    2.178, 2.112, 2.277, 3.20292, 2.8413, 2.046, 4.02948, 2.178, 
    3.15126, 3.20292, 1.947, 3.46122, 3.51288, 3.20292, 3.3579, 
    1.848, 1.782, 3.77118, 3.0876, 1.65, 3.97782, 1.914, 2.8884, 
    1.914, 3.82284, 3.7848, 3.51288, 3.77118, 2.99628, 1.881, 
    3.20292, 3.0996, 3.82284, 3.46122, 1.848, 1.947, 1.353, 2.079, 
    3.6162, 2.508, 1.881, 1.947, 3.8745, 3.51288, 1.881, 3.6162, 
    1.881, 3.30624, 3.71952, 2.013, 2.145, 3.30624, 2.112, 2.079, 
    3.15126, 2.046, 3.486, 3.0996, 3.82284, 1.782, 3.40956, 2.112, 
    3.46122, 2.6892, 3.0996, 2.079, 1.716, 2.99628, 4.08114, 
    2.99628, 1.947, 2.013, 4.08114, 3.1374, 1.31325, 2.343, 2.49, 
    3.51288, 1.815, 1.848, 1.494)),
row.names = c(NA, -200L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

EDIT2: Updated model and output
mixed.lmer.all <- lmer(Intertegular.Width ~ 
    Urban.Intensity*Sociality*Nesting + Urban.Intensity*Diet + 
    Genus + Sex + (1|SiteID), data=df)
summary(mixed.lmer.all); Anova(mixed.lmer.all)

Output:
REML criterion at convergence: 2893.8

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-8.8063 -0.5070  0.0109  0.5188  7.0897 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 SiteID   (Intercept) 0.003124 0.0559  
 Residual             0.091524 0.3025  
Number of obs: 6209, groups:  SiteID, 29

Fixed effects:
                                          Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)                               3.623485   0.025031 144.761
Urban.IntensityMEDIUM                    -0.000487   0.032435  -0.015
Urban.IntensityLOW                       -0.030261   0.032069  -0.944
SocialitySolitary                        -1.521940   0.022846 -66.619
SocialitySubsocial                       -2.230148   0.043176 -51.652
DietSpecialist                            1.085829   0.023517  46.172
SexM                                     -0.160474   0.008640 -18.573
Urban.IntensityMEDIUM:SocialitySolitary  -0.007449   0.027966  -0.266
Urban.IntensityLOW:SocialitySolitary     -0.055163   0.027705  -1.991
Urban.IntensityMEDIUM:SocialitySubsocial -0.024343   0.051024  -0.477
Urban.IntensityLOW:SocialitySubsocial     0.064915   0.049734   1.305
Urban.IntensityMEDIUM:DietSpecialist      0.007204   0.029618   0.243
Urban.IntensityLOW:DietSpecialist         0.065947   0.037770   1.746

Correlation matrix not shown by default, as p = 13 > 12.
Use print(x, correlation=TRUE)  or
    vcov(x)        if you need it

fit warnings:
fixed-effect model matrix is rank deficient so dropping 12 columns / coefficients
Analysis of Deviance Table (Type II Wald chisquare tests)

Response: Intertegular.Width
                                       Chisq Df Pr(>Chisq)    
Urban.Intensity                       2.7952  2   0.247184    
Sociality                         33289.6588  2  < 2.2e-16 ***
Nesting                                       0               
Diet                               7174.5682  1  < 2.2e-16 ***
Genus                                         0               
Sex                                 344.9539  1  < 2.2e-16 ***
Urban.Intensity:Sociality            15.0916  4   0.004515 ** 
Urban.Intensity:Nesting                       0               
Sociality:Nesting                             0               
Urban.Intensity:Diet                  3.5445  2   0.169953    
Urban.Intensity:Sociality:Nesting             0               
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

So what I gather from this, Urban.Intensity by itself does not impact body size, Sociality does, Diet does not, Sex does, Genus does not (there is no value here, not sure why it is set to 0)? If this means no, this is wrong because it definitely does impact body size.
But when looking at interaction terms, Urban.Intensity when considering Sociality does impact body size, but not when Urban.Intensity interacts with Diet. Nesting does not seem to matter for urbanization's impact on body size. Overall this should mean that Sociality is the only functional trait that does influence how urbanization influences body size. I guess this would mean it could be impacting solitary species much more greatly than social species or vice versa.
I guess with this output my last question is When looking at the significant interaction terms, is that ignoring the influence of Sex and Genus? Originally I wanted to leave Genus and Sex as random effects because I want to control for them - since they do impact body size regardless of anything else.

If you look at the lmer help file, it provides an example of performing significance testing for a fixed effect.

It's not clear whether any of Diet, Sociality or Nesting should be modeled as random effects here. It seems like each of them only has a few defined values, which would usually indicate treating them as fixed effects. If you have multiple genera of bees you might use genera as a random effect, to capture differences among genera not accounted for by Diet, Sociality or Nesting.

I had originally had that as a model, where the functional traits were fixed and Genera/Sex were random effects but my boss said that didn't make sense (but they're not a statitician). Yet somehow I am to model if functional traits have an effect on how urbanization impacts body size.

my model before this was:
model <- lmer(Head.Width ~ (Sociality|Nesting)+Diet + (1|Genus) + (1|Sex), data=df)
But then I didn't see how to include Urban.Intensity in this....I also get an error with this formula
  invalid subscript type 'list'"```

Even Sex might better be handled as a fixed effect, as there are presumably only 2 levels. The (Sociality|Nesting) term allows for random (Gaussian) associations of Sociality with outcome depending on Nesting, but I suspect that there are only a few levels of Nesting so that might not work well. The error message probably is from something in the way the data are formatted or supplied to the model, possibly unrelated to the model structure itself.

It might help if you could edit the question to provide a summary of your df data frame. I think that there might be a relatively simple way to accomplish your goal of evaluating the role of urbanization, but there isn't quite enough information here at present to be sure.

Ok I have added a subset of my data to test, otherwise the dataframe was too large I couldn't copy it to the main question.

I will mention that this subset data, the model fails to work but it is just to show you how the dataframe is set up. I tried to paste more of the data but I am way over the character limit so this was the best I could do.

I thought I need to keep it as ```Sociality:Nesting```` because sociality is nested within Nesting? Or is that only something to consider for random effects.

It looks like you don't have cases for all combinations of Socialilty and Nesting and Genus. That's why the model complains about "model matrix is rank deficient so dropping 12 columns" and why you thus have a lot of 0 values for df in the summary. For an interaction, include combinations or predictors that might influence each others' associations with outcome. If, for example, all of one Nesting type has the same Sociality then an interaction between them won't work.

The only thing that wouldn't occur in this dataset is that are no ground nesters that are subsocial and then no specialists are cavity nesters. There's nothing I can do about that to fix it. I also triedUrban.Intensity*Diet*Sociality*Nesting which gives the same results. I can understand a lack of interaction between Sociality and Nesting since there are some fixed interactions here...but it doesn't make sense for Genus to have 0 df when it is a separate term. I still don't know if the interaction between Urban.Intensity and the functional traits is controlling for Genus and Sex.

Most of your predictors might best be handled as fixed rather than random factors, all included together in the model.
When you have a predictor of primary interest, like Urban.Intensity here, you typically need to adjust for other variables that might also be associated with outcome. It doesn't make sense to examine the other variables separately, as leaving out any outcome-associated variable runs a risk of omitted-variable bias. That's one reason why your running "mixed models with each functional trait as a random effect individually" isn't the best way to proceed.
Another issue with your approach, as you discovered, is that you don't directly get a "significance" estimate for a random factor. The associations of levels of a random factor with outcome are assumed to follow a shared Gaussian distribution, here with 0 mean and a variance to be estimated. For example, with a random-intercept term, that's a Gaussian distribution of intercept values around the overall intercept of the model. You'll get a warning if the model estimates a 0 variance, but otherwise all you get is a variance (and the associated standard deviation) for a random factor.
The third issue is that most of your variables have too few levels to be handled reliably as random factors. This page outlines the rationale for why it doesn't usually make sense to specify any factor having fewer than about 6 levels as a random factor. That would rule out all except SiteID (with its many levels) as being appropriate to include as a random factor in your model. SiteID is a clear choice for inclusion as a random factor.
Go to a model that includes all of your variables together. In the default R treatment coding you use, the intercept is the estimated outcome when all categorical predictor variables are at reference levels (or 0 for continuous predictors). Each extra level of a fixed-effect categorical predictor then gets its own coefficient, expressing the estimated difference in outcome between that level and the reference level. If you want, you then can evaluate the "statistical significance" of all of those predictors in a single model.
Your predictor of main interest is Urban.Intensity, a factor with 3 levels. That needs to be included as a fixed effect, which will have 2 associated coefficients for differences of each of 2 levels from the reference (as you did in your example).
Including all the other variables will give a more reliable idea of how Urban.Intensity is associated with body size, as that takes the other variables into account. Including them all at once as fixed effects should be straightforward. As I count it, beyond the intercept you need to fit 2 coefficients for Year (1 less than the number of levels), 3 for Genus, 1 for Sex, 2 for Sociality, 1 for Nesting, and 1 for Diet. Added to the 2 coefficients for Urban.Intensity, that's only 12 coefficients.
The usual rule of thumb in a linear regression model, with the variability typical in bio/medical studies, is that you need about 15 observations per coefficient that your model is estimating. With over 6000 observations in your full data set, you could adjust not only for all the factors individually but also for many combinations of them, in interactions.
Choosing what interactions to include is where you apply your understanding of the subject matter. For example, if you think that the association between Urban.Intensity and outcome might depend on Diet, include a fixed-effect interaction Urban.Intensity:Diet. There then would no longer be simple associations of the Urban.Intensity levels with body size, but you might find richer associations that illuminate the underlying biology. You can also use interactions to  include combinations of the other variables you are adjusting for. For example, the interaction Sociality:Nesting would allow the association between Sociality levels and outcome to depend on the type of Nesting.
Think carefully about what combinations of variables might be associated with outcome or might affect the associations between Urban.Intensity levels and outcome. Include them in the model. Include SiteID as a random factor, to account for differences among sites that aren't captured by the other predictors. That gives you the best chance of reaching your goal.
In response to comments and other questions
First, if your fixed-effect predictor variables are linearly dependent, then regression software will typically report coefficients only for a linearly independent subset of predictors. It also won't estimate an interaction effect for a combination of predictors that doesn't exist. The software's choice of coefficients to report might depend on the order in which you enter the predictors into the model.
That's the situation with your data. In your data, if you have a Cavity-Nesting bee you know that it is also Subsocial, has a Generalist Diet, and is a member of the Bee1 Genus (evidently Ceratina). You have no Genus that is both Subsocial and Ground-Nesting.
That explains what was going on in this question when you tried to specify interactions and in one related question with interactions. You can only get a number of coefficients equal to the number of linearly independent predictors. You only have 4 different combinations of Sociality, Diet, and Nesting, each specific to a single Genus. So you only got an intercept plus 3 regression coefficients when you asked for all the interactions in that related question. Which 3 depended on the order you included them.
Similarly, linear dependence is why you have so many predictors in your model above with 0 Df. (I probably should have looked more closely at that limitation of the data before recommending that you model interaction terms.)
Second, it would be good to learn simple ways to inspect your data to alert yourself to such problems before you build the model. Although the str() and head() functions have important roles, sometimes it's more informative to use summary() and ftable() to get an overview. I'll illustrate with the data from another related question, where I've copied the structure into a data frame I called beeDF:
summary(beeDF)
#     Genus             Year          Month    Phenology 
#  Length:100         2021:22   May      : 4   Early:27  
#  Class :character   2022:47   June     : 6   Late :73  
#  Mode  :character   2023:31   July     :26             
#                               August   :32             
#                               September:30             
#                               October  : 2             
#                                                        
#  Urban.Intensity     Sex                SiteID  
#  HIGH  :18       Length:100         M01    :13  
#  MEDIUM:39       Class :character   L06    :10  
#  LOW   :43       Mode  :character   M04    : 9  
#                                     L01    : 7  
#                                     L04    : 7  
#                                     H04    : 6  
#                                     (Other):48  
#  Intertegular.Width   Wing.Wear         count  
#  Min.   :1.320      Min.   :0.000   Min.   :1  
#  1st Qu.:2.038      1st Qu.:0.375   1st Qu.:1  
#  Median :3.088      Median :1.000   Median :1  
#  Mean   :2.881      Mean   :1.520   Mean   :1  
#  3rd Qu.:3.513      3rd Qu.:2.125   3rd Qu.:1  
#  Max.   :4.432      Max.   :5.000   Max.   :1  

For example, at least with this data subset, you obviously can't get combinations of all 3 Year values with the Month of October.
The ftable() function can be particularly helpful. It gives counts of the numbers of observations in whatever combinations of predictors you want.
with(beeDF, ftable(Sex,Genus,Urban.Intensity))
#                 Urban.Intensity HIGH MEDIUM LOW
# Sex Genus                                      
# F   Agapostemon                    3     11   6
#     Bombus                         6      7  15
#     Ceratina                       0      2   1
#     Xenoglossa                     3      2   2
# M   Agapostemon                    1      6   8
#     Bombus                         2      1  11
#     Ceratina                       0      0   0
#     Xenoglossa                     3     10   0

That shows something perhaps otherwise hidden, at least in that data subset: there are no Male Ceratina, and no Ceratina at all from a HIGH Urban.Intensity.
The major point is that you can't distinguish all of the predictors that you might have hoped to distinguish. I suspect that a good choice will be to use Genus as a predictor, omitting Sociality, Nesting, and Diet. In discussion, note the Sociality, Nesting, and Diet characteristics of each species. A post-modeling comparison between Bee3 and Bee4 might help illustrate the association of Diet with your outcomes, in the context of Solitary Ground-Nesting, but you can't distinguish that from other factors that might also be associated with the Genus difference.

Thank you for this thorough explanation! I have one more question though regarding the Year variable. In my study I am actually also looking at interannual variation on body size so I do want to make some separate models that look at Year with functional traits and body size (because I have weather data for each year so I will be associating dry/wet season with functional trait and body size). In that sense and for my biological questions I would want to separate year and urbanization as separate models. Does that also make sense or would this be problematic to exclude a fixed effect?

New model is: model <- lmer(Intertegular.Width ~ Urban.Intensity:Sociality:Nesting + Urban.Intensity:Diet + Genus + Sex + (1|SiteID), data=df).
I get an output where all of these variables are significant. The largest chi-square is for Genus (makes sense, body size is definitely based on genus), followed by Sex (also makes sense), followed by Urban.Intensity:Sociality:Nesting and then Urban.Intensity:Diet. This means that urbanization does impact body size of bees and it DOES depend on traits? If I just focus on the last two fixed effects, is it ignoring the effects of Genus and Sex?

@KatherineChau A combined model is best to avoid omitted-variable bias, so include Year in the model with Urban.Intensity. The : for an interaction doesn't mean nesting for fixed effects. It represents a product that treats all of the included predictors equally. If you include interactions, then you should also include each predictor individually and all lower-level interactions. In R, you can do that easily with Intertegular.Width ~ Urban.Intensity*Sociality*Nesting + Urban.Intensity*Diet + Year + (1|SiteID).

@KatherineChau I'd be reluctant to comment on the model that only used : for the interactions without the individual predictors and lower-level interactions. Try my suggestion and maybe edit your question to show some of the results that confuse you. That works better than trying to discuss in comments.

Ok I added the model and it's output. I'm not sure how or what it means to include individual predictors/lower-level interactions.

@KatherineChau you need to use * instead of : in your function call to define the interactions. That will automatically provide the needed coefficients for individual predictors and the two-way interactions that underlie the 3-way Urban.Intensity:Sociality:Nesting interaction.

Ok If I understood correctly, I'm changing Urban.Intensity:Sociality:Nesting and Urban.Intensity:Diet to Urban.Intensity*Sociality:Nesting and Urban.Intensity*Diet. I have made an edit to the post above to reflect this new model and its output.

@KatherineChau I added a fair amount to the end of this answer, which I hope addresses the limitations of what you can do with your data and provides some additional hints. I now realize that each of your 4 Genera has a unique combination of Diet, Sociality, and Nesting, so that you can't distinguish independent associations of Diet, Sociality, and Nesting with your outcomes. That also addresses another question of yours. You'll have to choose which predictors to analyze and present to your audience. I think that Genus will be the best choice.

I cant use Genus. Genus is a given. That's why I want to control for Sex and Genus and just test functional traits.

But I thank you so much for all your advice and feedback. I've taken a ton of notes and I think I'm finally getting on a better track with this. I'll still need to meet up with some Stats modelers at my campus later but at least having all this broken down, so that I can discuss it with my boss and others now will be huge. Thank you! :)
